# New to 3d Modelling; Missing Faces/Normals When Uploading

Tags: normals, faces

I am very new to 3d modelling, just having finished my first model. I had the intention of uploading it onto shapeways for printing, as I have other 3d models. However I have run into a couple of problems. This is a pic of my model with backface culling on.

[image]

This is my fourth attempt to put it on shapeways, and I have been having problems so I double checked. I uploaded it to netfabb and I was suprised to see this!

[image]

Why are giant panels of the model missing? They clearly have faces and normals in blender, so what could it be? NetFabb is detecting not only that I have faces and normals incorrectly oriented but also it is just deleting or not detecting whole faces! I have tried reloading my normals and reorienting them a number of times in blender, and every time it simply flips them backwards and generally messes the model up. The model looks perfect in blender, and any attempt to change it just messes it up further. Repairing it in netfabb is no help, as it doesnt even detect the areas it says are incorrectly oriented, instead reorienting properly oriented normals the wrong way and even deleting detail like engines! Aargh!

Sorry for the long rant and I will upload the picture of the shapeways upload attempt when it comes online. Also, would posting my model help?

Comment: Adding your .blend will help. You can upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: Have you tried exporting your model in stl format?

Comment: There seem to be either double vertices or duplicated faces which cause Z-fighting and most likely mesh is non-manifold in some places. Probably this geometry was ignored after exporting and thus missing.

Comment: In Edit Mode, using Vertex Selection, do Shift+Ctrl+Alt+M and Blender will select for you all the *non-manifold geometry* on your mesh. Remember, if it has no volume, is infinitely thin, or has internal faces... it's *non-manifold*. Once you fix those areas you should be good.